# How to get drill-down tableviews working?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to figure out how to do a table view that drills down. I've manage to go from a table view Cell to a detailed view, and there are plenty of tutorials on how that's done with storyboards.

What I am trying to do is list some data in a Table view using a plist - I have that part working fine. What I now want to do is go down a few levels. For example:

```
Top level --> Level 1 --> level 2 --> etc --> detailed view.
```

Right now all I can seem to do is: Top level --> detailed view.

I just need to understand how - when tapping on one cell it will load the data for that cell in the next level down - like a category of some sort.

I'm using the iOS7 SDK and Xcode 5.

**Edit:**

So I looked at some other tutorials and modified them to my needs - this is what I need to do and what I am doing:

1. I'm using model objects - they get their data from a Plist, which root object is a Dictionary.
2. In the Plist data is like so:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>iDevices</string>
       <key>devices</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>name</key>
               <string>iPhones</string>
               <key>devices</key>
               <array>
                   <dict>
                       <key>name</key>
                       <string>1St Generation</string>
                   </dict>
               </array>
           </dict>
           <dict>
               <key>name</key>
               <string>iPads</string>
               <key>devices</key>
               <array>
                   <dict>
                       <key>name</key>
                       <string>1St Generation</string>
                   </dict>
               </array>
           </dict>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

So now I loaded the Plist into a custom data object and then I am using this object to populate an NSMutableArray like so:

```
-(void)loadData{
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"masterDeviceList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *deviceListDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    NSArray *allDevices = deviceListDict[@"devices"];
    NSMutableArray *iDevices = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in allDevices){

        RCDevice *iDevice = [[RCDevice alloc]initWithDictionary:dictionary];

        [iDevices addObject:iDevice];
    }

        self.devices = iDevices;

}
```

I call this method from my viewDidLoad on root TVC. Data loads correctly.

**Then I fill the tableView like so:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* cell;
    RCDevice *iDevice = self.devices[indexPath.row];

    if (iDevice.device) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoopBackCell];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DetailCell];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = iDevice.name; 
    return cell;
}
```

**Then this is where I am getting stuck:**

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSDictionary *rowData = self.devices[indexPath.row]; //Testing with this type
    RCDevice *iDevice = self.devices[indexPath.row]; //Also testing with custom object

    if ([self.devices[indexPath.row]isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loopbackSegue"]) {
            RCDeviceListView *rcDeviceListVC = (RCDeviceListView *)segue.destinationViewController;

                //TODO: Check if this gets called

            }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){

                __unused RCDeviceDetailView *rcDeviceDVC = (RCDeviceDetailView *)segue.destinationViewController;

                    //TODO Fille this in!

        }
        }
    else {
        if ([self.devices[indexPath.row]isKindOfClass:[RCDevice class]])
            {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loopbackSegue"]) {
            RCDeviceListView *rcDeviceListVC = (RCDeviceListView *)segue.destinationViewController;

                rcDeviceListVC.devices = iDevice.device; //This crashes
                rcDeviceListVC.devices = rowData[@"devices"]; //Also crashes

                rcDeviceListVC.title = iDevice.name;

            }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){

                __unused RCDeviceDetailView *rcDeviceDVC = (RCDeviceDetailView *)segue.destinationViewController;
            }
            }       //TODO Fille this is!


            }
}
```

**The app crashes with this line:**

```
rcDeviceListVC.devices = rowData[@"devices"];
```

**The error I get:**

> [*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCDevice
>   objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xed4aff0'

**Which I see why -I think:**

> rcDeviceListVC.devices

Is an array filled with RCDevice objects from my loadData method - it doesn't know what `rowData[@"devices"]` is.

**So I tried to modify that with this:**

```
rcDeviceListVC.devices = iDevice.device;
```

But that means I have an incompatible pointer. (NSString to an NSArray)

I am not sure how to fix this. I think it's because I don't fully understand what the prepareForSegue method is doing?

For the actual drill down - I am using a loopback segue and reusing the RCDDeviceListVC.

**What the app does now:**

1. It loads with the correct data in a Tableview. When I select a cell - the prepareForSegue method gets called - app crashes.

Or

2. It reloads the table view with the top level data and has a never ending drill down (loop)

**What I want the app to do:**

Load the first tableview with the data it's using now (iPhones, iPads) - tapping on a cell would list models of either iPads or the iPhones.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

This is the original code sample I tried to edit to use with my custom objects - instead of using NSDictionaries.

I tested out this code sample with my Plist and it works exactly as I need it to:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSDictionary* rowData = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loopbackSegue"]) {
        DrillTableController* drillVC = (DrillTableController*)segue.destinationViewController;
            drillVC.items = [rowData objectForKey:@"items"];
        drillVC.title = [rowData objectForKey:@"name"];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) {
        DetailsController* detailVC = (DetailsController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailVC.name = [rowData objectForKey:@"name"];
        //detailVC.imageName = [rowData objectForKey:@"imageName"];
    }
}
```

Why does it work with the above - but not when I try use my custom object?

> RCDevice

Comment: Maybe if you weren't using segues it would make more sense. It's similar to how many newer iOS developers don't truly understand reference counting since they've only ever used ARC. Try using the older methods of creating view controllers manually, without storyboards. Hopefully it will give you the insight you need to use storyboards in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try that to get a better understanding. I know we use the preparForSeque method to pass data along to the next view. Just not sure how to pass that data at the moment.

Comment: Create a custom init method for the `UIViewController` that will display the next layer of data. E.g. `initWithData:` - voila!

Comment: I am this is slightly off topic - but how does the preparForSegue "know" to go one level down in data - from iPhone to 3GS for example? This is what I need to understand. Then I will understand why I need an initWithData method. I know how to write such a method - I just want to understand why. Then maybe I will know next time why I need to do something?

Comment: That's up to you to decide how to model that "knowledge". If you're using a single view controller class, you can simply tell it what level to work with (as in `int`). Or instead of passing it the entire data block, just pass it the next level that it needs, and it knows to work with the top layer.

Comment: This is the original code - tried to modify it to my custom object: This code works but uses NSDict: 
________
    NSDictionary* rowData = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loopbackSegue"]) {
        DrillTableController* drillVC = >(DrillTableController*)segue.destinationViewController;
            drillVC.items = [rowData objectForKey:@"items"];
       }
_________
Can you tell me why this works and my custom object doesn't?

Comment: No I can't, I'd need to see the full code and these comments are getting too long. Consider updating your question.

Comment: Anyone else able to shed some light on the updated question? Still struggling with this :( Thanks!

Comment: I'm lost in your huge description... can you just do a simple sentence of what you want now ?

Comment: Sorry about the huge description. I have actually solved this issue mostly by experimenting and just trying out shit! :) I will post my solutions in an answer tonight and maybe someone can see if I did it okay? Give me two hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after a lot of debugging and playing with the code - this is what I came up with: see my last post:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/115623-drill-down-tableviews-need-a-push-in-the-right-direction-update-almost-got-it.html#latest

Edit: Incase link dies - 
Okay so the solution I came up with for my problem:

**What I realised:**

Using a 'reusable' UITableViewController like I was doing was giving me more issues than I knew what to do with. My issue was trying to navigate my data source and reloading the tableview with new objects one level down using the same tableview was proving to be an issue.

**This is how I eventually solved the problem:**

**I reworked the Plist file to store data like so:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>iDevice</string>
    <key>devices</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>iPhones</string>
            <key>devices</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>1St Generation</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>3G</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>3GS</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>4</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>4S</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>5</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>5S</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>5C</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>iPads</string>
            <key>devices</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>1St Generation</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>2</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>3</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>4</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Mini</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Now I needed to rework the RCDeviceListView controller to go through this data properly:**

```
RCDeviceListView.m
```

-

```
 (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    RCDevice *iDevice = self.devices[indexPath.row];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ModelViewSegue"]) {
        RCModelViewController *rcModelVC = (RCModelViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        rcModelVC.models = iDevice.device;
        rcModelVC.title = iDevice.name;



            //--Checking object for valid string--//
        NSLog(@"Object: %@", iDevice.device);


    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){

        __unused RCDeviceDetailView *rcDeviceDVC = (RCDeviceDetailView *)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}       //TODO Fille this in!
```

I came to the conclusion that I was passing an NSString for iDevice.name and what I was wanting was an NSArray of names. So I passed an array to the next view controller - then I did this in `RCModelViewController`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];
}

-(void) loadData

{
    NSMutableArray *allModels = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *deviceModels in self.models)
        {

        RCDevice *models = [[RCDevice alloc]initWithDictionary:deviceModels];

        [allModels addObject:models];

        }
    self.dictModels = allModels;
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.dictModels count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ModelCell"];

    RCDevice *device = self.dictModels[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = device.name;

    return cell;
}
```

I used the for loop here to pull out all the objects from the models array - much like I did in the first tableview.

The above does exactly what I need and works 100%!

Using the debugger to watch what my code was doing and what values it was passing etc really helped me towards a solution.

**Question**

Was there a way I could have reused the same UITableView and I just missed it?
Is this solution 'accepted' or is this considered a 'hack' and not a best guide at all?

Appreciate any feedback!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - updated my answer. Would love some feedback!